# How to resolve System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'NpgsqlTypes.PostgisPoint' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-web-api

I have value is UNKNOWN in postgresql, but Im sure if the data is Point, cuz the table name is geometry, so how to I convert it and return  it to json

I've been try to get it using string but return value is "NpgsqlTypes.PostgisPoint" and if I return it to integer, the message says "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'NpgsqlTypes.PostgisPoint' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'"

```
PointMaster point = new PointMaster
                {
                    point_id        = Convert.ToString(reader["point_id"]),
                    point_type      = (string)reader["point_type"],
                    longitude       = Convert.ToDouble(reader["longitude"]),
                    latitude        = Convert.ToDouble(reader["latitude"]),
                    approval_Flag   = Convert.ToString(reader["approval_Flag"]),
                    sp_geometry     = Convert.ToInt32(reader["sp_geometry"]), <--- This is the problem
                    msid            = Convert.ToInt32(reader["msid"]),
                    approval_date   = Convert.ToString(reader["approval_date"]),
                    creator_remark  = Convert.ToString(reader["creator_remark"]),
                    approver_remark = Convert.ToString(reader["approver_remark"]),
                    user_id         = Convert.ToInt32(reader["user_id"]),
                    approver_id     = Convert.ToInt32(reader["approver_id"]),
                    common_name     = Convert.ToString(reader["common_name"]),
                    db_flag         = Convert.ToInt32(reader["db_flag"])
                };
```

[image: this is the sample of the data]

the type data is Point, so what should i do for return it to json

Comment: what is the type of `sp_geometry `

Comment: I´m pretty sure whatever the type for `sp_geometry` is in your database, it´s not convertible to int. I rather assume it´s either `st_geometry` or a blob. Maybe even a string, but definitly no number. Why do you even want to convert to an int?

Comment: So what should i do ? I mean what the best way to return the data ?  The data is will be shown in maps, and the value is like blob type data

Comment: why not just cast to `PostgisPoint` instead of `int`? In order to transform that to json, you may use [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html).

Comment: Thanks with answer... the problem is fixed.. Can you write your comment in answer ? i will give you a checklist